# Share Audio File (MP3) android with Whatsapp trigger this error: "The file format is not supported"

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, mp3, whatsapp

I am trying to share an mp3 file with with an intent on Android. 
The code that I am using is the following:

```
    // uri creation
    audioFile=Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/raw/audio" + albumArtResId);

    // intent creation
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("audio/mp3");
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, audioFile);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Sound File"));
```

But after the selection of a specific contact in whatsapp a toast notification appears with the following message:"the file format is not supported".
I am quite sure that the problem is given by the URI creation but I have no ideas about how to solve it.

Comment: `android.resource://` is not a common `Uri` scheme and may cause problems with some apps. You may haver better luck serving sharing content via `FileProvider` or [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider).

Comment: @user3663743 Have you resolved the issue yet?